# Starting configurations for RNN and MLPs

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, hyperparameter

How do you go about choosing initial hyperparameters (layer size, # of hidden units in RNN and dense layers, etc.) when training RNNs and MLPs? How do you iteratively tweak these settings -- do you generally start with changing the number of layers, units, or optimizer?

Answer (score 1):

The first part of your question is very closely related to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181/how-to-choose-the-number-of-hidden-layers-and-nodes-in-a-feedforward-neural-netw) (*How to choose the number of hidden layers and nodes in a feedforward neural network?*). However, keep in mind that mostly, you figure out the layers and unit amount through trial and error.

Once you have found a suitable network architecture, you get on with the optimizer - you don't want your network to overfit the data for example. This part is related to reduce over/under fitting, but also making training faster by initialising your weights correctly. [A list of gradient optimization algorithms](http://sebastianruder.com/optimizing-gradient-descent/).

Ofcoures, you can always change the number of layers/units at any given time after that.