# Can a deep enough linear neural network (with activation functions) be able to learn anything?

Tags: neural-networks

Shouldn't a deep enough linear neural network (with activation functions) be able to learn anything, even recurrent and spatial patterns?
I could just flattened timeseries data or image data and pass it as input to a fully connected feed forward network. Why wouldn't it be able to learn from that data. This would be inefficient but would this be possible?
So Hypothetically I could replace an RNN or a CNN with a deep enough enough fully connected feed forward network?

Comment: Isn't this a [universal approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem)?

Comment: Maybe some things are not learnable from data? E.g. concepts like [Gödel's incompleteness theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems)

Comment: Yes, but does Universal Approximation Theorem also apply to functions that model temporal or pictorial data? So Hypothetically I could replace an RNN or a CNN with a deep enough enough fully connected feed forward network?

Comment: Yes, it just becomes hard to train. Also note that you can directly represent a convolutional layer as a matrix multiplication https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/21874/41576

Comment: I had seen a representation of CNN as simple linear network with shared parameters. Can the linear networks also replace RNN (hypothetically)?

Comment: It doesn't even have to be deep! One layer is enough if you have a buncha neurons

Comment: I found this resource: https://www.quora.com/If-a-single-layer-feed-forward-network-is-capable-to-approximate-to-any-degree-of-accuracy-why-is-deep-learning-successful

Comment: Lots of examples of functions that cannot be solved by NNs in this Q. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/563604/can-a-neural-network-with-only-1-hidden-layer-solve-any-problem/ I think you should [edit] to be more specific about the kinds of functions you are interested in