# Number of hidden units - function approximation

Tags: neural-networks

I have read [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181/how-to-choose-the-number-of-hidden-layers-and-nodes-in-a-feedforward-neural-netw) thread on how to select the appropriate number of hidden units and according to **Introduction to Neural Networks for Java** (second edition) by Jeff Heaton, one of the possibilities is - *The number of hidden neurons should be between the size of the input layer and the size of the output layer.*

However, I am trying to approximate some basic functions with neural networks in 3D space, having 2 inputs and 1 output, but if I choose only 2 hidden units, the approximation is not satisfaying at all. Only with more hidden neurons I get better results. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although these guidelines can be very good kick-starters for many, I don't quite follow them most of the time. Careful experimentation is the key, and this process is highly dependent on the data/problem. Your hidden layer can even have much more neurons than your input layer, instead of being in-between of input/output layers.

For example, consider a 2D case, not even 3D. I don't think using 1-2 hidden neurons will be enough to describe any kind of function, e.g. just to exaggerate: $f(x,y)=x\sin(y+e^{-x})+\cos\log|\sin(\sqrt{|x|}+y^7)|$. You'll probably need *more* neurons or layers to be able to learn such a function.

For the layers, in the link you provided, it says "*one hidden layer is sufficient for large majority of problems*". [Universal Approximation Theorem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Universal_approximation_theorem) actually addresses this. Having one hidden layer could indeed be sufficient, but there isn't a bound on the number of neurons. It can pay the price with exponentially large number of neurons to emulate the behaviour created by additional layers. Some [previous](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-65172-9_24) research indicate having two layers might be more useful than one layer case for some more complicated tasks.

There are also other [guidelines](https://www.heatonresearch.com/2017/06/01/hidden-layers.html) available, saying also that $n_{\text{hidden}}<2n_{\text{input}}$ or $n_{\text{hidden}}=\frac{2}{3}n_{\text{input}}+n_{\text{out}}$, or the one you've said. These are all starting points. In the end, it boils down to some sort of *informed* trial and error.