# Selection of the number of hidden neurons in MLP

Tags: neural-networks, python, cross-validation

I am trying to do MLP regressor for my data (6 INPUTS & 19 OUTPUTS). I am using 2 hidden layers MLP. I have 100 datapoints.

I am following the guidelines mentioned in [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181/how-to-choose-the-number-of-hidden-layers-and-nodes-in-a-feedforward-neural-netw#:%7E:text=However%2C%20neural%20networks%20with%20two,more%20than%20one%20hidden%20layer.) for the selection of the number of my hidden nodes.

According to the above source, the number of my hidden neurons should be between 6 and 15. So I've done various trial and error but I AM STILL GETTING A VERY LOW r^2 after CV.

However, when I select the number of my hidden neurons to be (200,200) I get a very good r^2 after CV. What's the logic behind that? Thank you.

Comment: Is the $R^2$ value measured on the training data or the testing data?

Comment: @Sycorax testing data.